# How to access websites from my web server remotely?

Tags: 14.04, server, dns, webserver

I am new to creating and managing dedicated web server.

I have installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS on this machine with LAMP and SSH packages.

I created some testing sites, and they work if I try to access them from any device that is connected to the same network, wireless or wired connection.

The problem is that I just can't access the sites remotely, using my neighbour's connection.

I set a static IP for the server and it happens that I have dynamic ip from my ISP. I created an account at noip.com and since my router has this service, I configured it to use NOIP.

I also bought from Go Daddy a domain, which is the one I can access locally,but not remotely.

So, anyone could help me sort this out?

Comment: Did you forward the ports in your router to the webserver?

Comment: You need to forward your domain you bought at Go Daddy to your dynamic domain and add port forwarding on your router for port 80.

Comment: Well, I didn't do port forwarding since I checked with port checkers and port 80 is open. But still I have to do it?

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida if you have NAT in your network then you have to do it (you most probably do have NAT).

Comment: Is there a way to check if I do have NAT? Also, if I install Bind9, would this whole thing be easier to config?

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida what's the IP of Ubuntu server? Can it access internet (try pinging 8.8.8.8)?

Comment: Pinging 8.8.8.8 is fine i get all packages with no errors.

Comment: And the IP of the server? Post output of `sudo ifconfig` please.

Comment: The ip is 192.168.25.7

Comment: You have a NAT, forward your incoming connections to that IP, port 80. And for the name you need a CNAME record added to your GoDaddy domains DNS.

Comment: Ok, the first part I understood and know how to do, but the second one on CNAME stuff, sorry and forgive my dumbness I don't understand, could you help me a bit further on this?

Comment: You have a dynamic DNS record (name) to grab your public IP which changes as I understand. So, you need to point your domain you got at GoDaddy to that dynamic record. https://uk.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236

Comment: @mbiber Ok, I did that, and now will wait for some time to see if it works.

Comment: Didn't work so far. I think I will do a fresh reinstall of ubuntu server and try using Bind9, what do you think @mbiber?

Comment: If you can access your sites locally then the server is fine. What do you need Bind9 for? How are you testing if your site is available to the public?

Comment: Bind to manage locally the dns. And to test I use my phone on 4G.

Comment: You don't need a DNS on the server. You need to set up your vhosts properly, forward port 80 to that local IP and set CNAME record. Provide info on what happens when you test your site from the outside. Tether your linux PC (if you don't have linux on your PC then boot live Ubuntu) to your phone and run `dig yourdomain.com` and `curl -IL yourdoman.com` please.

Comment: @mbiber I managed to get it working by signing up for managed dos service on noir and also bought a domain with them. Now everything is working just fine. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your LAMP is setup to be on a local network only and not via Internet connections.

This is what I used to create my LAMP:  https://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server  It's not the best English but it sure covers all the major points.

That said my only real gripe is it recommends 256mb of minimum RAM; which I feel is a little outdated considering todays RAM capabilities and thresholds (256GB DDR4 RAM for example). So I recommend a bare minimum of 1gb of RAM, but even more so I highly recommend whatever your mobos max ram threshold is then max it out to that amount. RAM has always been my issue with web hosting and is always the first thing I upgrade now because of previous issues and headaches.

Good Luck with your trusty tahr LAMP!!

Comment: @Software_Prograamineer Thank you, I will try that link and post the results later.

Comment: @Software_Prograamineer I checked the link and I see no difference between the install method that's there, from installing from disc and selecting the LAMP stack. Can you tell me where the diference is?

Comment: If the LAMP is setup with those steps then your issue may not be with your LAMP configuration at all but may be the domain address setup you have; including port forwarding, very important.